# Can I inline a org file inside another org file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In latex we can split a big document(paper.tex) into several tex files(abstract.tex,intro.tex ...) which can be inserted inline using \input{paper.tex}.

Is there a similar facility in org-mode?

Comment: Use http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `include` command i.e.

```
#+INCLUDE abstract.org
#+INCLUDE intro.org
```

This will inline `abstract.org` and `intro.org` in the current org file. See also the [org-mode documentation on include files](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Include-files).

Answer (score 0):

Without test, but I think you can just simply add the latex command `\input{paper.tex}` in any place of .org file you want. It will render the .tex file to final file.

PS: other option: Include-files which are mentioned in the comment.